# How do I Read Code Consisting Entirely of Punctuation?

Tags: security, deobfuscation

Over at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224673/can-malicious-code-fit-in-14-bytes, one of the comments mentioned the following 14-character code sample, in the setting of malicious logic:

`:(){ :|:& };:\n`

No other context was provided. Naturally, this is impossible to google. I'm not a member of that site, and thus I cannot ask the original commenter for clarification.

So,

- What does this code do? If nonobvious, why is it malicious?
- What language is this?
- In the future, when faced with a wall of punctuation, how can I find out the above two? Is there a website/tool for this, or some other reasonable method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this code do? If nonobvious, why is it malicious?

The code you mentioned is of Linux [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). Fork bomb is a function that is used to conduct Denial-of-service attack on the system.

**Let's breakdown the code:**

The basic structure of a Linux bash function is:

```
function(){
 arg1=$1
 arg2=$2
 echo 'Hello'
 #perform_something on $arg
}
```

Comparing the fork bomb function with the above syntax of bash function, it would be like following:

```
:(){
:|:&
};:\n
```

Where:

> :()

It defines a function named as ":".

> :|:

The function ":" calls itself recursively and pipes the output to another call of the function ":" (which makes the fork bomb unstoppable unless you reboot your system).

> &

This puts the function execution to the background.

> ;

; terminates the function.

> :

It calls the function (fork bomb) without arguments because fork bomb function requires no arguments to run.

> What language is this?

The language is Bash.

> In the future, when faced with a wall of punctuation, how can I find out the above two? Is there a website/tool for this, or some other reasonable method?

It will need you to use google and search with breaking down the punctuation string in parts.

**Warning:** Do not run this code on your Linux system as it will make your system crash and unresponsive unless you reboot it.

Comment: One thing: Googling any amount of punctuation seems futile, especially if you can't identify the language alone. Otherwise, good explanation.